# Windows 10 screen timeout is set. Something turn on the screen after it has been switched off by timer settings

Tags: windows-10, logging, screensaver, wake-up, spyware

- My screen timeout settings is set to 5 minutes for both options (On battery + When plugged in).
- My sleep settings is set to 15 minutes from battery and never when plugged in.
- Blank screen saver is set to 3 minutes with enabled display logon screen option.

**Items 3 and 4, makes me feel confused:**

1. After 3 minutes my black screen saver is locking my pc and making my screen black. Which is correct.
2. After 5 minutes my screen is turning off. Which is also correct.
3. After 16 minutes my screen is turning on without any reason. The distance of time when it happens is always the same.
4. After approx. 17 min and 25 seconds my screen is turning off (it is not a black screen saver, my screen is turned off). After that my screen is always off until there is an action from my side like mouse moving or key pressing.

My question is why point 3 and 4 happening? And how to log which process is making that happening? The biggest fear is that probably there is some spy background process is running.

I would appreciate for any help.